# Why is C++ allocating such a large space in memory for my dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays

`readFruit.name` is initialized to `NULL` before I try to initialize it as a char array. I included `size` to see if that was the culprit but it is exactly what it should be depending on my input. No matter what length `tempString` is, `readFruit.name` is allocated around 25 "characters" in memory and they're all garbage. Why isn't it being allocated a space the size of `tempString.length()` and how can I fix it?

relevant CPP

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &is, Fruit &readFruit)
{

string tempString;
is >> tempString;
int size = tempString.length();
readFruit.name = new char[tempString.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < (int)tempString.length(); i++)
{
    readFruit.name[i] = tempString[i];
}
for(int i =0; i < CODE_LEN; i++)
{
    is >> readFruit.code[i];
}
return is;
}
```

Relevant H file (constructor)

```
#ifndef _FRUIT_H
#define _FRUIT_H
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
enum { CODE_LEN = 4 }; 
enum { MAX_NAME_LEN = 30 };
class Fruit
{
private:
    char *name;
    char code[CODE_LEN];
public:
    Fruit(const Fruit &temp);
    Fruit(){name = NULL;};
    bool operator<(const Fruit& tempFruit);
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Fruit& printFruit);
    bool operator==(const Fruit& other){return *name == *other.name;};
    bool operator!=(const Fruit& other){return *name != *other.name;};
    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream& is, Fruit& readFruit);
};
#endif
```

Comment: “No matter what length tempString is, readFruit.name is allocated around 25 "characters" in memory” – how do you know that? Nothing in your code actually shows the internal allocation size.

Comment: You probably want to allocate n+1, one for the 0 terminator.

Comment: I know that because I debugged my code and saw the actual memory locations being allocated. All but the input were garbage.

Comment: I suppose allocation was the wrong word but it's no need to down vote my question. The system was reading 25 or so characters after the char array pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to print `readFruit.name`, it will display garbage value until it finds a null termination, that's what I assume you saying 25 characters "*all garbage*"

Allocated memory like this :

`readFruit.name = new char[tempString.length()+1];`

And after `for` loop do:

`readFruit.name[i] ='\0'; // C strings are null terminated`

Comment: Or make the loop run until `i <= ...`, instead of `i < ...`

Comment: Or better yet, instead of the loop do a `strcpy`, or maybe even `strdup`.

Comment: @Dialecticus One _could_ use `strdup()`, but the the deallocation would need `free()`.  As new/delete is preferred in C++, recommend staying with `new`.

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, you need to null-terminate your `name` character array. Right now you copied all characters, but you need to have a binary zero character at the end for all string functions to work. So you need to allocate one char more and write a `'\0'` to it.

That said: use `std::string` for your fruit's name. There is no reason to help yourself to a ton of self-made bugs by staying with a character array.